# Python SMTP Errno 10060

Tags: python, smtp

Can someone give me some insight as to why both this:

```
mailServer = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
```

and this:

```
mailServer = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
```

Are saying this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in <module>
mailServer = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Shuttlecock_new\python\lib\smtplib.py", line 242, in __init__
(code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Shuttlecock_new\python\lib\smtplib.py", line 302, in connect
self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Shuttlecock_new\python\lib\smtplib.py", line 277, in _get_socket
return socket.create_connection((port, host), timeout)
File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Shuttlecock_new\python\lib\socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
raise err
error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

- I'm in China.
- I have a VPN. I tried it with and without the VPN.
- I have, many times before, used this code to send e-mails from my g-mail account. Suddenly today, I got this error.
- Gmail, if accessed through my chrome browser, works fine. Albeit, it's taking an unusually long time to send simple e-mails...hmmm

Comment: Try a regular SMTP mail client.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try specifying a timeout (requires Python 2.6+):

```
smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587, timeout=120)
```

or try connecting via SSL instead of TLS/STARTTLS (with and without `timeout`):

```
smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465)
```

Comment: The problem actually naturally corrected itself. Since it appears as though the problem was on gmail's end, the timeout and SSL suggestions are both very good. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. The call to `mailServer = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)` just hang there, without doing anything. I can't even quit the program. It stays in the background forever!

But adding the timeout parameter solved the problem! It returns immediately and I can sent email through gmail SMTP server successfully!

Not sure why though!

Answer (score 1):

Look my friend, see the line

```
mailServer = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587, timeout=120)
```

and put YOUR_USERNAME after the 587 number, like this

```
mailServer = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587, "YOUR_USERNAME", timeout=120)
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason why you were getting this error was because the password you generated for the gmail had expired in a way so just try regenerating another one using the app password in your gmail....
i tried that and it worked perfectly for mine

Answer (score 0):

well i had the same problem and the way i solve it was using a VPN . cuz i noticed it was a socket problem (sock.connect(sa)) and sa means South Africa . So i simple connected my PC to an SA server and tried sending SMTP again . it worked

AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\socket.py", line 837, in create_connection
sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond