# Sending an email via gmail through a python application

Tags: python, email, python-2.7

as indicated by the title I am having trouble sending an email via my gmail account through a python application.I have searched online for a solution but nothing seems to solve it and I thought I might ask here.
My code is the following:

```
FROMADDR = "myemail@gmail.com"
LOGIN    = FROMADDR
PASSWORD = "mypass"
TOADDRS  = "varis81@hotmail.com"
msg = "Test message"
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.set_debuglevel(1)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(LOGIN, PASSWORD)
server.sendmail(FROMADDR, TOADDRS, msg)
server.quit()
print "E-mail succesfully sent"
```

I get the message:

```
socket.error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

I tried different ports but it doesn't work also.I also tried hotmail but it causes the same problem.I am using Python 2.7 (don't ask :) ) on a Windows 7 machine developing on Eclipse using PyDev.

Any help would be great!
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since I cant post comments yet I'll have to attempt an answer..

Judging by this: [Python SMTP Errno 10060](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979678/python-smtp-errno-10060)
Perhaps a timeout would help?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Actually I had tried that before and it didn't help.It causes the same problem.

Comment: Hmm, I have a feeling this is probably a blocked port / port forwarding issue. Have you tried using port 25 as outgoing?

Comment: This is the default right?How can I set it explicitely?I am going to test it in another network to see if it is working there then.

Comment: Try changing the following line: 
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 25)

Comment: Ah yes, I have done this and it causes also the same problem.I thought you said that my pc had its port 25 blocked and it can not forward connections.But now that I think it it shouldn't be possible since the error message is connection part did not respond.

Comment: Aside from logging in to your router and forwarding port 587 or 465 you could try using smtp.googlemail.com instead. Port 25 is likely blocked by your ISP, stick to the other two but make sure they are open. Will a "telnet smtp.gmail.com 587" timeout? If so you may need to forward it on your router.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the same construct on one of my servers.  My code is below.

The only difference is the extra `.ehlo()` after '.starttls()`.  This *should* not be the issue; from the [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2487.txt):

```
5.2 Result of the STARTTLS Command

The client SHOULD send an EHLO command as the first
command after a successful TLS negotiation.
```

According to the RFC, the server should not sever a connection if the client does not send `ehlo` after `starttls`, but Google could be more restrictive on their SMTP server. I'd check that first.  (I've seen providers tighten down on these kinds of conditions to reduce spam, see [Mailinator's 2007 writeup](http://mailinator.blogspot.com/2007/01/architecture-of-mailinator.html) for instance.)

It could also be filtered ports -  try running the code in the REPL and confirm which line is exceptioning, if it's the `connect()` you'll know it's network.  If it's after, it's likely your usage of `smtplib.`

Of note, I also experienced occasional unclean shutdowns, resulting in the try/except around `.close()`.

```
import smtplib
s = smtplib.SMTP()
s.connect("smtp.gmail.com")
s.ehlo()
s.starttls()
s.ehlo()
s.login("from@gmail.com", "frompass") 
s.sendmail("fromname@gmail.com", toAddr, bytes)
try:
    s.close()
except: pass
```