# I am getting TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] while sending email from python smtp

Tags: python, smtp, gmail, smtplib

I am a beginner in python. i setup a script to send email from gmail using smtp in python.
i got following error

```
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\socket.py", line 832, in create_connection
sock.connect(sa)       
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

i tried to find all solution from stackoverflow and google but failed any solution.
here is what i tried to fix and failed
i generate a new password from app password from gmail setting , i tried to changed port number but failed.

```
import smtplib

my_email = "myemail@gmail.com"
password = "mypassword"

with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com") as connection:
   connection.starttls()
   connection.login(user=my_email, password=password)
   print("logged in")
   connection.sendmail(from_addr=my_email, to_addrs="myanotheremail@gmail.com", msg="Hello")
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error using the following code which I believe is similar to yours:

```
import smtplib

my_email = "myemail@gmail.com"
password = "password"

with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", port=587) as connection:
    connection.starttls()
    connection.login(user=my_email, password=password)
    connection.sendmail(
        from_addr=my_email,
        to_addrs="otheremail@yahoo.com",
        msg="Subject:Hello\n\nThis is the body of my email.")
```

To fix it I used smtplib.SMTP_SSL() instead of smtplib.SMTP(), changed the port to 465 and commented out the line with tls:

```
import smtplib

my_email = "myemail@gmail.com"
password = "password"

with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", port=465) as connection:
    # connection.starttls()
    connection.login(user=my_email, password=password)
    connection.sendmail(
        from_addr=my_email,
        to_addrs="otheremail@yahoo.com",
        msg="Subject:Hello\n\nThis is the body of my email.")
```

To arrive to this conclusion, I referred to:
https://realpython.com/python-send-email/ and https://stackoverflow.com/a/6979864/20520732